# How to get LinearLayout's children as a viewgroup?

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout, viewgroup

I have a `LinearLayout` with 9 static children. I want to get 2 children (in order such as `childAt(0)` and `childAt(1)`) as a `ViewGroup` in order to apply an animation. 
I don't want to create a new `LinearLayout` because I need to remove the children from its parents first and it will actually remove the children and I don't do it since I just want to animate these children at together.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/to" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/subject" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to get child 2 and 3 as `ViewGroup`.

Comment: since LinearLayout is already a viewgroup, is there a way to get child 2 and 3 as viewgroup?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `ViewGroup.addView(View)`?

```
viewgroup.addView(lview.childAt(0))
viewgroup.addView(lview.childAt(1))
```

Comment: This won't work, because you need to create a viewgroup.  I am not sure if we can merge 2 children in the onLayout().                                               `ViewGroup viewGroup = new ViewGroup() {
            @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
                // ?
            }
        }`